# Swift UIButton : Selected Emoji disappear

Tags: swift, uibutton, emoji, selected, sender

I am using 5 UIButton and I'm getting emoji string in this buttons. But the problem is, when I click the button, emoji disappear on the screen. I guess this is highlighted or selected color problem, but I didn't figure out. What should I do for this?

**My code :**

```
func buttonSelectedNot(){
    button1.selected = false
    button2.selected = false
    button3.selected = false
    button4.selected = false
    button5.selected = false
}

@IBAction func favoriteButtonAction(sender: UIButton) {

    // Save Data
    buttonSelectedNot()
    sender.selected  = !sender.selected;
    if (sender.selected)
    {
        sender.selected = true
        emojiString = (sender.titleLabel?.text)!
        print(emojiString)

    }
    else
    {
        print("Not Selected");

    }

}
```

**Snapshots :**
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, never worked with emojistrings, but your code is a bit weird. When a button is clicked you set all buttons to `selected = false` then you set the `sender.selected = !sender.selected` (which means that `sender.selected = true`, provided that the sender is one of the buttons in `buttonsNotSelected()`). Then you check if `sender` is selected and if it is selected you set it to true again and then add the emojistring.

What happens if the `sender.selected = true`? Well, you will set it to false using `buttonsNotSelected()` and then you will invert it and set it to true, even though it probably should be `false` (provided that `sender` is one of the buttons in said method). Not sure if this is any issue though, but it seems to me like the reason for the emoji to disappear is because `.selected` is not set correctly.

Try to clean up your code a bit

```
func buttonSelectedNot(){
    button1.selected = false
    button2.selected = false
    button3.selected = false
    button4.selected = false
    button5.selected = false
}

@IBAction func favoriteButtonAction(sender: UIButton) {

    // Save Data
    sender.selected  = !sender.selected;
    if (sender.selected) {
        emojiString = (sender.titleLabel?.text)!
        print(emojiString)

    } else {
        print("Not Selected");
    }

    // SET ALL BUTTONS, EXCEPT SENDER, TO FALSE

}
```

Comment: Oh I solved the issue. No problem to selected button. When I select the button, I activate selected from the sender. I'll answer my question :) thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem. The problem is, You need to set titlelabel color for the button. If you don't, it's disappear.

Solved code :

```
func buttonSelectedNot(){
        button1.selected = false
        button2.selected = false
        button3.selected = false
        button4.selected = false
        button5.selected = false
    }

    @IBAction func favoriteButtonAction(sender: UIButton) {

        // Save Data
        buttonSelectedNot()
        sender.selected  = !sender.selected;
        if (sender.selected)
        {
            sender.selected = true
            emojiString = (sender.titleLabel?.text)!

            **//need to set title color for the button.**
            sender.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: .Selected)
            print(emojiString)

        }
        else
        {
            print("Not Selected");

        }
        sender.selected = true

    }
```

**Snapshot :**
[image]

And it's look perfect :D